# ERROR: Function is not a static data member of “Class” - C++

Tags: c++, class, arduino

I'm very sorry if this has already been answered somewhere, but after hours of searching, I couldn't find or understand anything.

Being quite new to OOP, I'm exercising myself with classes by trying to create a class where I pre-defined a 2 dimensions character matrix. I keep getting the following error:

*error: 'char Matrix2d::keyss [4][4]' is not a static data member of 'class Matrix2d' char Matrix2d::keyss [ROWS][COLS] =*

My header is the following:

```
const int ROWS = 4;
const int COLS = 4;

class Matrix2d
{
  public:

   char keys [ROWS][COLS];

  private:

};
```

And My .cpp being this:

```
char Matrix2d::keys [ROWS][COLS] =

{
{'1','2','3','A'},
{'4','5','6','B'},
{'7','8','9','C'},
{'*','0','#','D'}
};
```

This is a simple code made to run with an arduino keypad.

Thank you in advance for any help and hope I gave enough information as it's my first time posting here.

Comment: You need an instance of a `Matrix2d` object to be able to assign to its `keys` member.

Comment: To initialize your array rather use  an initiializer list at your constructor function.

Comment: *Sorry if some of you have already seen this, but it has been suspended as I was in the wrong topic section*

Comment: What is the data for? Should there be only one copy of the data during the run-time of the program? Or should each instance (each object) of `Matrix2d` have its own unique and distinct member variable?

Comment: Change `char keys [ROWS][COLS];` to `static char keys [ROWS][COLS];`  Review the difference between static and regular data members of a class. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static

Comment: Sorry I couldn't get back earlier but thank you very for everyone's help. The solution from @bruno worked for me. Thank you !

Comment: "The solution from @bruno worked for me"  Then please mark bruno's answer as correct. This helps others that may come across your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the class is defined like that :

```
const int ROWS = 4;
const int COLS = 4;

class Matrix2d
{
  public:

   char keys [ROWS][COLS];

  private:

};
```

that means *keys* is an attributes of the instance of *Matrix2d*, but the form

```
char Matrix2d::keys [ROWS][COLS] =

{
{'1','2','3','A'},
{'4','5','6','B'},
{'7','8','9','C'},
{'*','0','#','D'}
};
```

defines and initializes an attribute of the class *Matrix2d*, this is incompatible

---

If you want an attribute of the class (a 'static' one) do

```
const int ROWS = 4;
const int COLS = 4;

class Matrix2d
{
  public:
     static char keys [ROWS][COLS];    
};

char Matrix2d::keys [ROWS][COLS] = {
  {'1','2','3','A'},
  {'4','5','6','B'},
  {'7','8','9','C'},
  {'*','0','#','D'}
};
```

If you want an attribute of instances having that default value do

```
class Matrix2d
{
  public:
     char keys [ROWS][COLS] = {
       {'1','2','3','A'},
       {'4','5','6','B'},
       {'7','8','9','C'},
       {'*','0','#','D'}
     };
};
```

In both case I encourage you to change the visibility